# Able to GET in Postman, but not in browser

Tags: api, react-redux, react-router, postman

Developing a React app and when calling the API in browser I receive a 404 error on the call, though the rest of the page renders successfully:

[image]

However, calling the same route in Postman returns successful:

[image]

It's not unique to this single route. Other API calls previously working through browser are resulting in the same error while calls through Postman continue to be successful.

Package.json for reference:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-alert": "^7.0.2",
    "react-alert-template-basic": "^1.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Did you correctly set up a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) in your package.json?

Comment: Perhaps not? Added my package.json for reference.

Comment: Did you set up CORS on the API?

Comment: What's the domain variable in postman?

Comment: The domain variable is http://localhost:4000 which is preceded by http:// (stack is removing the http:// when saving this comment).

Comment: Apologies, I am not sure if I have set up CORS. To add some context my application was working fine until I had to shut down my computer to install some mandatory updates. Upon restarting the server, application and database the issue has appeared.